# Why Wildfly can not find a jsp file from deployment?

Tags: java, jsp, myfaces, wildfly-10

Sorry for my english.

I use **wildfly-10.1.0.Final** and **myfaces1.1** .

- When I use an exploded deployment, I can access only the static jsp files. The dynamic jsp files, generated with **Freemarker** are not found.
- When I use the packaged deployment, all jsp files (static and dynamic) are not found.

I have no errors to the server side.

Can someone help me please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you using freemarker? Can you paste some code and exact error stack trace ?

Comment: hello @BilboBaggins for your quick reply.I use **freemarker** to put external different parameters into jsp files. The jsp file is created without problem, there no error stack trace, I have just a 404 not found to the client side.

Comment: In that case you should check for your URLs. Are you accessing correct urls? or the urls that you are accessing are correct ?

Comment: Yes I access to the correct url. In fact, on the first access the jsp file is not found, but when I try to access a second time it works. I don't understand why the first access doesn't work, even if jsp file exists.

Comment: This could be connected with fact that JSP would compile itself when first time access. Then the cached version (compiled jsp) is served. You can read more about this in [developer.jboss.org](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/PrecompileJSPs) PS. Your English is perfectly fine - don't worry to much most of people is not native speakers so we understand that learning additional language might be difficult.

Comment: Thanks @BilboBaggins and @AlexBaranowski. I find a solution. When I use debug mode step by step, it works, even if it is the first acces. To reproduce this behaviour by coding i have added `Thread.sleep(2000)` at the end of file generation, and it works.

Comment: Good that you find a solution but I don't think Thread.sleep is a good/ideal solution, you should do some research